# Como exibir os Posts de um usuário?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

Estou tentando exibir os posts do usuário no `perfil = link_to 'perfil', user_path(user)`

Os dados do usuário aparecem, mas quando tento mostrar posts do usuário vem o erro:

> NoMethodError in UsersController#show undefined method 'posts' 
>   for #<`Class:0x007f4c48fdbb50>`

O código mostrado com erro

users_controller

```
 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @posts = User.posts  #aqui a linha marcada
end
```

posts.controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_with(@posts)
  end

  def show        
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def update
    @post.update(post_params)
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

model/posts.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PublicActivity::Model
    tracked owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }

    has_many :coments
    belongs_to :user
    validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }

end
```

model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  has_many :coments
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships
  has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user

  has_many   :messages,   dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :properties, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :partnerships
  belongs_to :city
  has_one    :state, through: :city
  has_one :profile

  mount_uploader :avatar, ImageUploader

  validates :terms, acceptance: { message: "Você precisa aceitar os termos de uso" }
  validates :name, :city_id, presence: true

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    if user
      user
    else
      registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
      if registered_user
        registered_user
      else
        user = User.create(
          name: auth.extra.raw_info.name,
          provider: auth.provider,
          uid: auth.uid,
          email: auth.info.email,
          password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
          remote_avatar_url: auth.info.image.gsub('http://','https://').gsub('picture', 'picture?type=large')
    )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Acredito que o problema está no seu model de `User`. Nele existe `has_many :posts` ? Clique em [edit] e coloque esse outro Model por favor.

Comment: @gmsantos coloquei o model, e tem has_many :posts O mesmo erro acontece tambem quando tendo exibir '@properties = User.properties'

Answer (score 1):

Você guarda o usuário na variável **@user**, porém chama o método posts direto da classe **User**

Use a váriavel **@user** no lugar de **User**

```
def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @posts = @user.posts  #MUDAR ESSA LINHA
end
```